# imagenes en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Buenas he intentado introducir un gif en la interfaz de tkinter en python desde windows pero me aparece este mensaje cuando tengo todos los archivos en la misma carpeta:

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "seguridad.gif": no such file or directory

Comment: En principio la ruta a la imágen, no es correcta, sin ver como pasas la ruta y a estructura de tu proyecto es difícil ayudar no obstante.

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar un gif, debes mostrarlo fotograma a fotograma como una animación.

Un gif animado consiste en una serie de cuadros en un solo archivo. Tk carga el primer fotograma, pero puede especificar diferentes fotogramas pasando un parámetro de índice al crear la imagen. Por ejemplo:

`frame2 = PhotoImage(file=imagefilename, format="gif -index 2")`

Si carga todos los marcos en PhotoImages separados y luego usa eventos de temporizador para cambiar el marco que se muestra (label.configure (image = nextframe)). El retraso en el temporizador le permite controlar la velocidad de la animación. No hay nada que le proporcione el número de cuadros en la imagen que no sea la creación de un cuadro una vez que supera el recuento de cuadros.

> FUENTE : https://riptutorial.com/es/tkinter/example/30058/uso-de-formatos--gif-